# Meaning of 'Never Mind'

Tags: meaning-in-context

I can't stop thinking about the meaning of this part of a song text I recently heard:

'Never mind, I'll find someone like you.'

I've already taken a look on the internet but I found different translations to my native language (German).
Does 'Never mind' in this case means the same as: 'I don't care, I'm sure I'll find someone like you' or does it rather mean:
'I will never find someone like you'. Or has it a completely different meaning?

Comment: Also, it can be rendered *[don't bother; don't concern yourself](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/never%20mind)* or *forget about it* (don't keep it mind). Literally, more like an imperative *Never you mind*, with mind as a **verb**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Never mind** in this use generally [means](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/never_mind) something similar to *don't worry about it* or *it's not important*.

So, in the [song](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/adele/someonelikeyou.html), she's not telling the person that she doesn't care, she's telling them that she still cares about them but since they've moved on and found someone new, they should not worry about her feelings and that she'll find someone else eventually.